# lightgbm.basic.LightGBMError: Sum of query counts is not same with #data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, lightgbm, k-fold

I was try to do hyper-parameter tuning using `GroupKFold` and `RandomSearchCV`. I have cross checked the shapes, they are matching. How to solve this error?

**Code:**

```
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
qids_train = X_train.groupby(["query_id"])["query_id"].count().to_numpy()
flatted_group_train = np.repeat(range(len(qids_train)), repeats=qids_train)


gbm = lightgbm.LGBMRanker(
    objective="lambdarank",
    metric="ndcg",
    is_unbalance=True,
)

gkf = GroupKFold(n_splits=5)
cv = gkf.split(X_train, y_train, groups=flatted_group_train)
grid = RandomizedSearchCV(gbm, params_grid, n_iter=10, cv=cv, verbose=2, refit=False)
grid.fit(
    X=X_train,
    y=y_train,
    group=qids_train,
)
```

---

**Error:**

> lightgbm.basic.LightGBMError: Sum of query counts is not same with
> #data

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback, and preferably an example dataset.

Comment: I guess the groups in the fit params don't get split up correctly for the cv...

Comment: @BenReiniger I found on [LGBMRanker](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRanker.html#lightgbm-lgbmranker) documentation, that *scikit-learn doesn’t support ranking applications yet*. So, I used `optuna` for hyper-parameter tuning instead of sklearn.

Comment: I'd suggest adding that as an answer, preferably including an optuna snippet.